# Issue in getting current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I want to get current location of device. Code works fine normally. It gives location if user has not changed app authorization status for location service. I am also able to check if user has denied permission for location service.

*Issue is when user deauthorizes the app to use location service and then authorizes again*. In this case, after this if I try to get location it gives `nil` though it called

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

delegate method with status `3` i.e. `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`.

**Code to get current location :**

```
CLLocation * location = self.locationManager.location;
```

**Getter method :**

```
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager
{
    if (!locationManager)
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
    }

    return locationManager;
}
```

**CLLocationManager delegate method :**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    DLog(@"Location authorization changed : %d", status);

    // If user has denied permission for location service
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        DLog(@"Location service denied.");

        // If authorization status changed method is already called, then SDK will not call again on same object.
        // Thus, set CLLocationManager object to nil so that next time we try to get location, it will create a new object,
        // and that will send message about authorization status changed.
        self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
        self.locationManager = nil;
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        // If authorization status changed method is already called, then SDK will not call again on same object.
        // Thus, set CLLocationManager object to nil so that next time we try to get location, it will create a new object,
        // and that will send message about authorization status changed.
        self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
        self.locationManager = nil;
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {

    }
}
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: in the above you set the locationManager.delegate to nil if authorization is revoked... do you ever set it again to the appropriate class?

Comment: just noticed you also set the locationManager to nil...

Comment: Based on your comments in the code you recreate the `locationManager` object somewhere - are you sure this is being triggered when you set `self.locationServiceDisabled = false` ?

Comment: @Volker I set it again getter method. Added getter method in question.

Comment: I don't see you ever starting to update your location ( cllocationmanager startupdatinglocation )

Comment: @Paulw11 `self.locationServiceDisabled` flag is not used anymore. I updated my code in question.

Comment: @NilsZiehn Its not calling that delegate method. And, it should give location on `CLLocation * location = self.locationManager.location;` line.

Comment: In the apple docs it is state about the location property of the locationManager:"The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been retrieved."  For this reason you need to somehow update your iPhones location! In order to make this happen you should call the locationmanager startupdatinglocation... method!

Comment: @NilsZiehn Yes, that was the reason. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.locationManager.location` is `nil` since you never started updating the location.

In the apple docs it is stated about the `location` property of the locationManager:

> The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been
>   retrieved.

For this reason you need to somehow update your iPhones location!

[Apple Docs CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

Usually this means you want to call

`[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`

but you can also use

`[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]`

Comment: I would like you to add whole text of your comment here. That would make this answer much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the delegate to nil you will get no updates about authorization status changes, isn't it?

```
self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
```

I think you should keep the delegate in order to receive authorization status updates and then call the startUpdatingLocation method in order to get the current location.

```
- (void)startUpdatingLocation
```

Comment: If you care to see my code carefully then its clear that in getter method I set delegate again.